# Obscure pointer declaration

Tags: c++, c

I have a question which is in some way, I guess, completely trivial: what's that (and why)?

```
const float *(*const*)(int)
```

My understanding is that it is a "pointer to a constant pointer to a function taking an int as argument and returning a pointer to constant float".

Is it correct ?

How to "mentally parse" `(*const*)` ? Especially as there is no name, at first I didn't know where to start. I think that the only possibility for a "name" would be to put it like that: `*const *name` as other combination are invalid (if I am correct), so then "name is a pointer to a constant pointer ...".

Is this reasoning valid ?

Thanks !

Comment: I try to avoid mind-bending definitions like this by breaking it down into components using typedef.

Comment: c giggerish to EN:                             "http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=const+float+*%28*const*+foo%29%28int%29"

Comment: For anyone having difficulty plugging the above code into a compiler try putting it as a parameter in a function prototype `int foo(const float *(*const*)(int));` which is the same as `int foo(const float *(*const* var_name)(int));`

Comment: This online tool will generate documentation for pointer initializations: http://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that reasoning is valid. Put it on the right of all '*'es that are not within function parameter lists and on the left of all []'es that are not in function parameter lists. Then you have

```
const float *(*const* name)(int)
```

Then read it as usual. From thereon and even how to find the correct place for the name, [there are](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html) many tutorials how to parse this on the internet.

For C++, you may want to look into [geordi](http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/geordi/).

```
< litb> geordi: -c int name;
< geordi> Success
< litb> geordi: make name a const float *(*const*)(int) and show
< geordi> -c float const *(*const* name)(int) ;
< litb> geordi: << TYPE_DESC(const float *(*const*)(int))
< geordi> pointer to a constant pointer to a function taking an integer 
          and returning a pointer to a constant float
```

You can then do analysis on the syntax of it

```
< litb> geordi: show parameter-declaration and first decl-specifier-seq
< geordi> `int` and `float const`.
< litb> geordi: make name an array of 2 pointer to function taking int and 
        returning pointer to float and show
< geordi> -c float const *(* name[2])(int );
```

It lets you mix C with English

```
< litb> geordi: make name an array of 2 pointer to (float const*(int)) and show
< geordi> -c const float *(* name[2])(int);
```

As you see, it's pretty powerful.

Comment: Thanks for the link to "geordi", it looks impressive !

Answer (score 12):

You are correct that name goes after `*const*`. If you plug the line `const float *(*const* name)(int)` in [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org), it will tell you that it means "*declare name as pointer to const pointer to function (int) returning pointer to const float*"

As for mental parsing, I just remember that `R (*p)(A)` is a pointer to function. Therefore `R (**p)(A)` is a pointer to pointer to function, and all it takes at this point is to remember how `const` and `*` interact.

Answer (score 2):

Just work from the outside in.

You have something of the form:

```
U D(V)
```

so you have something function like.

something-something is a function taking `int` and returning `const float*`.

For `(*const*)` you work backwards to get the `const` in the right place (although being symmetrical that doesn't even matter here!). `*const*` ~ "pointer to const pointer to", just like (say) in `int * const * p` `p` is a pointer to a `const` pointer to an `int`.

Putting it all together: pointer to const pointer to function taking `int` and returning `const float *`.

Comment: Thanks ! It was not too complicated.